# Mostrar todos os posts do facebook em uma lista

Tags: javascript, facebook

Eu possuo inúmeros perfis e fan pages que devo controlar o conteúdo.

Entrar uma a uma dá um trabalho gigantesco. Por isso, estou fazendo esta aplicação para mostrar todos os posts por ordem de data, separados por perfil/fan page.

Através do Facebook Graph eu consigo resgatar os dados da tabela STREAM, porém estes não são suficientes para se montar o post completo (eu não encontrei os links, photos, etc, por exemplo).

Estou tentando receber o JSON via JSONP desta forma:

```
var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx";

$.get(fburl, function(data){
    console.log(data);
},'jsonp');
```

Porém, retorna message: "Unsupported get request.".

Qual a melhor forma de resolver esta situação?

Comment: Isso parece ser problemas com a token de permissão.

Comment: Isso me dá um HTTP 400. A URL está correta?

Answer (score 2):

O problema estava no access_token. Desta forma funcionou perfeitamente:

```
var fburl = "https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxx?access_token=yyyyyyyyy";

$.get(fburl, function(data){
    console.log(data);
},'jsonp');
```

Comment: Você pode marcar a sua própria resposta como respondida.